# C# TableLayoutPanel and really annoying behaviour

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm really tired for figuring out what's going on.

http://postimg.org/image/ymotfd8ab/
Buttons on left side should be at upper left corner and scale with resized window. Button and text box in upper left corner should stick to the left side of screen. In the middle I want to make animation or just change image by pressing buttons from left side.

I want my design to be resizeable or able to switch between 1024x768/1280x1024/1366x768. But I cannot figure out how to make it happend. This freaking Panels and TLP are so weak...

http://postimg.org/image/bbn83jiz3/

When I put my panel described as animation/picturebox in TLP It cannot be higher than my box becouse it is in the same row. When I put it in panel, and select it DOCK - FILL it will fill whole screen instead of middle. Please give me some tips to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

For `TableLayoutPanel` child controls, there are 2 properties in Designer called `RowSpan` and `ColumnSpan` that allow you to define one control on several rows or/and columns.

It seems that what you are looking for is to set your `PictureBox`'s `RowSpan` property to 8. But, as your `PictureBox` seems to be in a `TableLayoutPanel` (in your screenshot), you must modified the `TableLayoutPanel`'s `RowSpan` instead of the `PictureBox`'s one.

```
tableLayoutPanel6.RowSpan = 8 // number of rows the control must use in its parent TableLayoutPanel
```